# How to serialize Java properties to JSON

Tags: java, json

Can I have JSON serialize properties (I mean Java bean getter and setter properties) of POJOs?

Comment: getter/setter are methods not properties.

Comment: What else would you serialize? "properties" are the fields in the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) and [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) projects will be able to help you there.  Here is an [article](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2008/12/entry_121.html) about serializing a Java object using Jackson.  Essentially, you can do

```
new JavaTypeMapper().writeValue(new File("out.json"), myObject);
```

Comment: JavaTypeMapper was replaced with ObjectMapper. http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-30  Also, note that writeValue(File, Object) outputs to a file, while writeValueAsString outputs JSON as a Java String.